# Talend Using HTML in tSendmail

Tags: html, email, html-email, talend

Forgive what might be a very stupid question, but i've been trying to get this to work for a while and have had no joy. I did look around and can't actually find anything that has the answer already.

I have a job in Talend which uses a tMySQLInput to tFlowToIterate to tSendMail which worksreasonably well in producing individual emails based on data from a table in my database.

However, i need the sent email to look reasonably pretty and so i have tried to use HTML - but i am failing badly.

I have tried putting the following into the the message section on the tSendMail component, but it throws up a lot of errors (appreciate the HTML itself is rubbish, i'm just trying to get the concept right before moving on):

```
"<html>"+
"<h2>Statement</h2>"+
"<p>Dear row1.firstname</p>" +
"<ul>" +
"<li>Your online statement is now available" +
"<li>Please logon and check" +
"</ul>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the encoding type to `HTML`, select the [tSendMail component](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/14.35+tSendMail), then advanced settings menu and choose the `HTML` encoding. You can also refer to [this great post](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=35580) in the Talend community.

Comment: Hi. I have amended the encoding type to HTML and i had already discovered that article which I have been trying to follow. The only bit i am not clear on is  the tJava component. I have added this and inserted  context.Message = " My HTML Code " but that generates errors. Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: @monkeyb33f Since its a java String, you have to escape special characters in your message, try to display the message before using it in tsendmail.

Comment: thanks. After a lot of playing around, i got it to work. I was also incredibly stupid but forgot to create the context.message in the 'Contexts' of the job! Still i got there. Thanks for your help.